# SharePoint Online Page Stats

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can someone help me on my requests below. Please let me know if it's possible?

1. To be able to get the LifeTimeViews and LifeTimeUniqueViews for all the News posts in the News Webpart of the Homepage(/sites/Home) of our tenant.
2. To be able to get the "Views and Unique Views" for /sites/Home.aspx page month over month i.e., every month report for the last 180 days.

**I would like to know if there is anyway I shall create a script that can get into Home site > News Webpart > All News Posts; and get the LifeTimeViews and LifeTimeUniqueViews properties of the All news posts particularly in that webpart.**

*It's SharePoint Online Modern Sites.
*New Posts will be selected multiple SharePoint sites in our Tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve this.

SharePoint does not support customizing modern web part.